# Why my bike shows petrol missing before 2000 RPM in all gears?

Tags: engine, motorcycle, carburetor, gears, gear-ratio

I am using Hero Karizma R (225cc, 5 gears).
Recently I feel a missing in all gear befor 2000 RPM. Sometimes my bike turn off due to this missing. Usually it happens at 1st/2nd gears. After 2000 RPM there is no problem. I checked it in a road by riding my bike below 2000 RPM in 1st and 2nd gears and it shows missing. The problem in 3rd/4th and 5th gears are feeling while the accelerator's starting position immediatly after the gear shift.

*Please let me know if i missed anything in the above descripion, so that I can update my question.*

Comment: what are you missing? are you missing power or are you missing the feeling of the gears engaging.

Comment: Is it going into neutral?

Comment: I think the missing is misfiring?

Comment: i know something is missing somewhere. But we need to find out the missing.....

Comment: while give throttle engine shows missing of petrol. At that time I feels the engine may turn off.Thats all

Comment: petrol missing? is it fuel injection or carburetors? if carbs then it sounds like a jet is clogged.

Comment: @kannan  please respond to the 1st question above.   Give us your definition of 'missing'.

Comment: missing power. i.e. the rpm goes low and engine get turn off if it is in first gear.

Answer (score 2):

Your Carburettor might be clogged. Clean it along with the air filter and you should be good to go.

Also check if your "choke" chord is not faulty since it will tend to send a rich mixture to the engine which will stall it at low RPM and you get that "Missing" feeling but more importantly your fuel efficiency is affected.

Comment: Agree that it really sounds like something to do with the carb. Could be dirty/clogged or just improperly jetted on the low end.

Answer (score -2):

(**NOTE:** The following is a Google Translation)

Your carburetor is trapped in the garbage ... clean him, then the bike will be right ... this happened to me as well

(*original text:* Tumhare carburetor mai kachara fsa hua hai..... Usko clean kro fir bike sahii ho jaayegi.... Mere sath bhi aisa hi hua tha..... )